# Windows Batch - How to set variable with "<" in it?

Tags: windows, batch, cmd.exe

I'm trying to set a variable with a prompt ... Here is my example : AEIO<5845da-8

Here is my code :

```
@echo off
set /p password= what is the passwd : 
echo the password is %password%
pause
```

When i try to set AAAA or BBBB or 58-3s it works, but when i set : AEIO<5845da-8, it's not working.. I think the issue is with "<"...

But i need it in my project.

I got the following error when i launch my script :

The specified file could not be found...

Comment: `<` is not the only symbol which will cause problems... `>`, `|`, `^`, etc. Solution - use the instrument other than batch processing.

Comment: See my answer, thank's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is easy, here is the new code that works correctly :

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
set /p password= what is the passwd : 
echo the password is !password!
pause
```